# dracaena lemon lime brown leaves and pale color

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, dracaena

here are a few images

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I would like to know what the problem is. I was watering it carefully but it gets worse. I have tried and trimmed some of the roots but it doesn't seem to be helping at all.